# Google Tag Manager; code position, site speed and measurement

Tags: javascript, performance, google-tag-manager

We currently have GTM installed just before the closing body tag, and it works fine. We run our entire GAP install through it and use it for a couple of other tags. No problem.

We put it in the bottom, as we have an aversion to JS in the head of the page, due to speed (download and render blocking) and dependency concerns; we try to keep the page simple so that it is fast, and have had some success in that area.

However, in an attempt to further measure, understand and improve site speed, I'd like to fire off some user timing events to GAP. A specific example: the first image on the page to load is our masthead logo, it actually serves as a good indication of render start.

Here's the question: *must* the GTM script be above the logo for it to reliably capture the onLoad event for that image?

Comment: It's possible that the image could load before GTM and its child scripts are fully loaded, if you have a lot of Images or external files such as js and CSS files then the browser can only manage a certain amount of parallel requests at once, you might be better loading GA at the top so that you can log events and load other non time critical items at the bottom using GTM

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really wanting to avoid that if possible. In other words, I want to have my cake and eat it! A solution I have considered is having a JS variable in the head of the document, then using plain old javascript inline in the onLoad handler to write a time to it, then read that time back in the footer in GTM.

Comment: Personally, I dont think it would make that much of a difference, the GA script is very likely to be already cached in the users browser as most websites use it already, To do this your way, you'd have to implement cross browser code to detect the image(s) have finished loading for not much.. if any significant gain. That's just my opinion though, Someone else may come along with a better solution.

Comment: The GTM container is asynchronous. It means that it doesn't block the rendering of the page as it is being downloaded and executed. It also injects all the tags asynchronously. Putting it at the end of the page code is defeating its purpose of firing tags as quickly as possible and in an unobtrusive manner. You should put the container as high as possible in your source code.
GTM also has some built in events that you can use to measure page rendering time: container loaded, DOM ready, window.onload.